# recalibrate ball in pong so the edge hits first, not the centre in Processing

Tags: processing, pong

I've recently built a game of pong for a UNI assignment in Processing, but whenever the ball hits the top, bottom, side of the screen or the 'paddle' it only bounces back once half the ball is off the screen. I just want the edge of the ball to hit first rather than the centre, but am unsure where my code is going wrong. I hope this makes sense, I'm a definite beginner.

Here is my code for reference

```
   //underwater pong

float x, y, speedX, speedY;
float diam = 10;
float rectSize = 200;
float diamHit;
PImage bg;
PImage img;
int z;

void setup() {
  size(920, 500);
  smooth();
  fill(255);
  stroke(255);
  imageMode(CENTER);
  bg = loadImage("underthesea.jpg");
  img = loadImage("plastic.png");
  reset();

}


void reset() {
  x = width/2;
  y = height/2;
  
 //allows plastic to bounce 
  speedX = random(5, 5);
  speedY = random(5, 5);
}


void draw() { 
 background(bg);

  image(img, x/2, y);  
  rect(0, 0, 20, height);
  rect(width/2, mouseY-rectSize/2, 50, rectSize);
 
 //allows plastic to bounce 
  x += speedX;
  y += speedY;


// if plastic hits movable bar, invert X direction
    if ( x > width-30 && x < width -20 && y > mouseY-rectSize/2 && y < mouseY+rectSize/2 ) {
      speedX = speedX * -1;
    } 
  

// if plastic hits wall, change direction of X
    if (x < 25) {
      speedX *= -1.1;
      speedY *= 1.1;
      x += speedX;
    }


  // if plastic hits up or down, change direction of Y   
  if ( y > height || y < 0 ) {
    speedY *= -1;
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to run your code because I am missing the background and plastic images, but here's what's probably going wrong. I'm not 100% since I do not know the dimensions of your images either.

You are using imageMode(CENTER). See [the documentation](https://processing.org/reference/imageMode_.html) for details.

From the docs:

> imageMode(CENTER) interprets the second and third parameters of image() as the image's center point. If two additional parameters are specified, they are used to set the image's width and height.

This treats the coordinates you input into the image function as the center of the image.

Your first issue is that you are placing your image at `x/2` but doing all your collision checks with `x` in mind. `x` does not represent the middle of your image, because you're drawing it at `x/2`.

Then I'm not sure if you are doing your horizontal collision checks right, as you are checking against hardcoded values. I do know you are doing your vertical collision checks wrong. You are checking if the center of the image is at the top of the canvas, `0`, or the bottom of the canvas, `height`. This means that your image will already have moved out of the screen halfway.

If you want to treat the image coordinates as the center of your image, you need to check the left edge  of the image at `x - imageWidth / 2`, the right edge at `X+ imageWidth / 2`, the top edge at `y - imageWidth / 2` (remember the y coordinates are 0 at the top of the canvas and increase towards the bottom) and the bottom at `y - imageWidth / 2`. [Here](http://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/rect-rect.php)'s a great website which goes into more detail on 2d collision detection, i'd highly recommend you give it a read. It's an awesome website.